# Modal con contenido dinámico desde PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, modal

```
<?php for($i=0; $i<count($datos); $i++){ ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $datos[$i]["id_entrada"]; ?></td>
<td><img id="myImg" src="../img-usuarios/<?php echo $datos[$i]["entrada_imagen"]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $datos[$i]["entrada_titulo"]; ?>" width="300" height="300"></td>
<?php 
   $categoria->get_categoria_por_id_entrada($datos[$i]["id_categoria_entrada"]);
 ?>
<td><button class="btnAdmin" style="background-color: #2196f3"><i class="far fa-eye"></i> Contenido</button></td>
```

Quiero mostrar este contenido de la base de datos en un modal y que cambie con cada ciclo (Sin usar Bootstrap ni Jquery)

```
<?php
  $categoria->get_contenido_por_id_entrada($datos[$i]["id_entrada"]);
?>
   </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Pregunta: **1.**  `get_categoria_por_id_entrada` no está en un `td` pero está en el medio de un `tr` y no hace nada. tengo que suponer que `get_categoria_por_id_entrada` saca (`echo`) un td? Después parece que vuelves a poner el `get_contenido_por_id_entrada` justo antes de cerrar el `tr`.

Comment: **2.** La pregunta parece ser _como crear un modal con javascript utilizando estos datos_.  Si la pregunta es de javascript sería útil editar tu pregunta y agregar el HTML resultante, para que la gente pueda entender que quieres conseguir

Comment: No se entiende exactamente qué necesitas realizar.